# After updating webpack-dev-server and webpack some modules are requested but doesn't exist

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server

My project uses Vue.js and Typescript. I updated webpack and webpack-dev-server and now some modules are missing when I try to run in development mode.

**More info**:

My packages versions:

```
"npm": "6.0.0",
"webpack": "^4.8.1",
"webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
"webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.5"
```

Command to run app in development mode in my `package.json`ǜá sa:

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --inline --hot --display-error-details

The error returned is:

```
module.js:545
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack/bin/config-optimist'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/project_folder/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js:64:1)
```

And I already tried:

1. Reinstall webpack;
2. Remove node_modules and run `npm install` again;
3. Manually put this file (config-optimist.js) code in folder ([found here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/95131831/)) but after that, another module was missing too.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incompatible webpack-dev-server version is looking for a file that is not there anymore. Upgrade and it should fix the issue.